# ASCII to UCS2 encoding java code

Tags: java

I have a requirement for converting a String(which is usually be in ASCII char set) to UCS2 character set and then needs to be converted to Base 64.

I could find the code for Base 64 conversion, but facing issue with encoding to UCS2.
It would be great help if any help provided for converting a string to UCS2 character set in java.

Thank you,

Comment: Aren't Java string already UCS2 (or UTF-16)?

Answer (score 3):

When you read your data into a `String` variable the internal representation will already be unicode, but when you do `mystring.getBytes()` the returned bytes will be the String encoded by the default-encoding of the current platform.

If you want to get UTF-16 (which is basically the same as UCS-2 (a.k.a ISO 10646), see [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14)) use

```
mystring.getBytes("UTF-16").
```

Comment: *Basically the same* but not exactly. UTF-16 adds a BOM that is not part of UCS2 so you should strip it off with `Arrays.copyOfRange(s = mystring.getBytes("UTF-16"), 3, s.length)` and pad it so the number of bytes is even... See [the site you mentionned](http://www.unicode.org/faq/unicode_iso.html).

Comment: use "UTF-16BE" to avoid the BOM.

Comment: @jtahlborn even UTF-16LE in my case. Thanks (again)!

Answer (score 2):

I initially started with `getBytes("UTF-16")` as [mentionned by @piet.t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20899103/1098603) but there are a few caveats to consider when dealing with UCS2: it encodes each character as exactly two bytes (see [complete code chart](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html)) and doesn't use any BOM. `getBytes("UTF-16")` adds a 2-bytes BOM `0xfeff` that should be removed when encoding, and added back when decoding.

I also noted the last byte should be discarded during decoding (but I'm encoding mostly ASCII, it might be wrong to do that with other character codes)

EDIT: After @jtahlborn hint about using UTF-16BE, I ended up using UTF-16LE (which does not produce any BOM, even not the extra `0` that UTF-16BE was giving) with the following two encode/decode methods, which work well in my use-cases (adding XP TIFF tags):

```
public static byte[] encodeUCS2(String s) {
    try {
        return s.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return new byte[]{};
    }
}

public static String decodeUCS2(byte[] e) {
    try {
        return new String(e, "UTF-16LE");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that there is not much need of specific encode/decode methods in that case, as they're bare no-exception-thrown replacements for `getBytes()`/`new String()`.

Comment: The UTF-16 BOM is two bytes and the order indicates the endianness.

Comment: if you use "UTF-16BE", you won't get the BOM.  also, the utf-16 BOM is two bytes.

Comment: Thanks @jtahlborn, but it still gave me a leading extra `0`. UTF-16LE didn't and could encode/decode properly without the ugly byta array hacking. Thanks!

Comment: that's not an "extra" leading 0, that's the first byte of the first character.  it depends which byte order you are expecting.  utf-16 defaults to big endian which is why i said "LE".