# How to convert padbytes function to coldfusion

Tags: node.js, coldfusion

I have the following code in node and I am trying to convert to ColdFusion:

```
// a correct implementation of PKCS7. The rijndael js has a PKCS7 padding already implemented
// however, it incorrectly pads expecting the phrase to be multiples of 32 bytes when it should pad based on multiples
// 16 bytes. Also, every javascript implementation of PKCS7 assumes utf-8 char encoding. C# however is unicode or utf-16.
// This means that chars need to be treated in our code as 2 byte chars and not 1 byte chars.
function padBytes(string){
  const strArray = [...new Buffer(string, 'ucs2')];

  const need = 16 - ((strArray.length) % 16);
  for(let i = 0; i < need; i++) {
    strArray.push(need);
  }

  return Buffer.from(strArray);
}
```

I'm trying to understand exactly what this function is doing to convert it. As I think I understand it, it's converting the string to UTF-16 (UCS2) and then adding padding to each character. However, I don't understand why the `need` variable is the value it is, nor how exactly to achieve that in CF.

I also don't understand why it's only pushing the same value into the array over and over again. For starters, in my example script the string is `2018-06-14T15:44:10Z testaccount`. The string array length is 64. I'm not sure how to achieve even that in CF.

I've tried character encoding, converting to binary and stuff to UTF-16 and just don't understand well enough the js function to replicate it in ColdFusion. I feel I'm missing something with the encoding.

EDIT:

The selected answer solves this problem, but because I was eventually trying to use the input data for encryption, the easier method was to not use this function at all but do the following:

```
<cfset stringToEncrypt = charsetDecode(input,"utf-16le") />
<cfset variables.result = EncryptBinary(stringToEncrypt, theKey, theAlgorithm, theIV) />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

We followed up in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173236/discussion-between-ageax-and-leeish) and turns out the value is ultimately used with [encrypt()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html). Since encrypt() already handles padding (automatically), no need for the custom `padBytes()` function. However, it did require switching to the less commonly used [encryptBinary()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encryptbinary.html) function to maintain the UTF-16 encoding. The regular encrypt() function only handles UTF-8, which produces totally different results.

[Trycf.com Example:](https://trycf.com/gist/81bf264e78531baea64439b3e6a8964f/acf?theme=monokai)

```
// Result with sample key/iv: P22lWwtD8pDrNdQGRb2T/w==
result = encrypt("abc", theKey, theAlgorithm, theEncoding, theIV); 

// Result Result with sample key/iv: LJCROj8trkXVq1Q8SQNrbA== 
input = charsetDecode("abc", "utf-16le");
result= binaryEncode(encryptBinary(input, theKey, theAlgorithm, theIV), "base64);
```

---

> it's converting the string to utf-16
>   (ucs2) and then adding padding to each character.
>   ... I feel I'm missing something with the encoding.

Yes, the first part seems to be decoding the string as UTF-16 (or UCS2 which are [slightly different](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-ucs-2-and-utf-16/)). As to what you're missing, you're not the only one. I couldn't get it to work either until I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898074/ascii-to-ucs2-encoding-java-code#comment53588926_20899103) which explained "UTF-16" prepends a BOM. To omit the BOM, use either "UTF-16BE" or "UTF-16LE" depending on the endianess needed.

> why it's only pushing the same value into the array over and over again.

Because that's the definition of [PCKS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). Instead of padding with something like nulls or zeroes, it calculates how many bytes padding are needed. Then uses that number *as the padding value*. For example, say a string needs an extra three bytes padding. PCKS7 appends the value `3` - three times: `"string" + "3" + "3" + "3"`.

The rest of the code is similar in CF. Unfortunately, the results of charsetDecode() aren't mutable. You must build a separate array to hold the padding, then combine the two.

*Note, this example combines the arrays using CF2016 specific syntax, but it could also be done with a simple loop instead*

**Function:**

```
function padBytes(string text){

  var combined = [];
  var padding = [];
  // decode as utf-16
  var decoded = charsetDecode(arguments.text,"utf-16le");

  // how many padding bytes are needed?
  var need = 16 - (arrayLen(decoded) % 16);
  // fill array with any padding bytes
  for(var i = 0; i < need; i++) {
     padding.append(need);
  }

  // concatenate the two arrays
  // CF2016+ specific syntax. For earlier versions, use a loop 
  combined = combined.append(decoded, true);
  combined = combined.append(padding, true);

  return combined;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
result = padBytes("2018-06-14T15:44:10Z testaccount");
writeDump(binaryEncode( javacast("byte[]", result), "base64"));
```

Comment: Can't wait to check this out tomorrow. Thanks. Its part of a bigger encryption project, hope this works. Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure sure it's completely correct. Will have to take another look later today.  It works with ascii, but there are some differences with more exotic characters and I'm not sure why yet...

Comment: I'm still not getting the same results... I think because of the following. If I output the value of strArray it looks like this `2 0 1 8 - 0 6 - 1 4 T.....` The length of the array is 76, basically showing those spaces. I was messing around with adding those via `charsetEncode( javacast("byte[]", [0] ), "utf-8")` between each letter earlier, but even now with utf-16le the length of the string doesn't match nodes.

Comment: You're saying the example value "2018-06-14T15:44:10Z testaccount" isn't matching? When I checked the base64 encoded output and it was the same with node and CF2016. Though again, I'm not sure it holds true for more exotic characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm saying anymore.  I'm trying to figure out why the same two strings (one in Cf and one in node) don't result in the same value on the other end. I think partly after combining, I'm getting and array where the first value is the decoded binary object and the next 4 values are the number 4. Coldfusion doesn't like your binaryencode function on the resulting array.

Comment: Is this what you're doing? https://trycf.com/gist/74f5e86c97ef87c3c065da44c1037783 . Looking at the bytes, they're the same except for an extra "0 116 0" on the end in CF. Yet the base64 output is the same as node.  /acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Is your output CF16 only? I run the same on my server and I get 
`The value [B cannot be converted to a number.` on the binaryEncode output at the end. but yes, the base64 result matches what I need. https://trycf.com/gist/22c30c3cdf5ff4d5410efeeb5926d085/lucee5?theme=monokai See my function padbytes2. It produces the same result but I can't run `binaryencode(javacast(....` on my server.

Comment: Basically I need to get the result of this function back into a string in order to run AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption on it. So I think what you did is perfect, just, how do I get it back into a string. Here is the error in gist... https://trycf.com/gist/905e0a5232d2fce63523809eda5649dc/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: *"I can't run binaryencode(javacast(.... on my server. "* Weird... what version of CF is it running? **(Edit) Never mind #1. I see it's CF11, correct?** *"to run AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"* Silly question, but why can't you use Encrypt()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173236/discussion-between-ageax-and-leeish).